# Terminate Python in Terminal (control-C just printing ^C) macOS 10.12

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, terminal, macos-sierra

So I've been using control-z to stop my python scripts, but I recently noticed they were still active in the activity monitor and can only terminate them there. Control-C doesn't work and only prints out ^C. Perhaps the combo got remapped? Any suggestions on how I can figure this out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Problem solved!

Comment: Excellent!  I posted my comments as an answer.  Could you please say what you did to resolve the problem?

Comment: Ctrl-D is usually mapped to send EOF in shells when interactively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `CTRL+Z` suspends a process and places it into background, see `man bash` and search for **job control**.

On the OS X standard bash, `CTRL+C`sends a `SIGINT` (interrupt signal) to the foreground process but also prints `^C`. `SIGINT` can be ignored or handled by the running process.

By default python handles `SIGINT` and converts it to a a `KeyboardException` If your scripts handle a general exception like `except Exception:` or similar (a very bad idea) then it could ignore the `CTRL+C`.

Check your scripts for signal handling and general exception handling.

To check for remapping on the terminal type `stty -a` and look for `cchars` and you should see `intr = ^C;` and `susp = ^Z;`.

Comment: Thanks, my program had an async handler, which was blocking the SIGINT.